# Javascript - getPropertyValue gives wrong height

Tags: javascript, height, padding, getpropertyvalue

```js
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("d1");
let b = window.getComputedStyle(a[0]);
let c = b.getPropertyValue("height");
alert(c);
```

```css
.d1 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">Test test test</div>
```

The above code alerts `18px` but the `height` of the `div` element is actually `48px`. It looks like that it doesn't take in consideration its `padding`. How can I alert its real `height`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `height` property does not include `padding`. Try using [`.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) instead, which does include padding. Here's from the docs:

> `clientHeight` can be calculated as: CSS `height` + CSS `padding` - height of horizontal scrollbar (if present).

```js
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("d1");
let c = a[0].clientHeight;
alert(c);
```

```css
.d1 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">Test test test</div>
```

Comment: Far more discussion in the flagged duplicate. Please take the time to flag basic questions for closure as they more often than not have the benefit of multiple answers offering a greater range of explanation and possible solutions.

Comment: @pilchard I'd say this question is kind of an edge case ([signpost dupe](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/20/linking-duplicate-questions/) maybe?). Sure, the dupe you flagged happens to have the same answer, but the questions are different. The dupe asks how to do something but this question asks for help with a bug, so it's certainly not just a useless carbon-copy.

Comment: The question here boils down to *'How can I alert its real height?'* (in the OPs own words) which seems as a clear a dupe of *'Get div height with plain JavaScript'* as one could ask for.